# How to enter any text value in a online PDF Editbox using Webdriver in java

Tags: pdf, selenium-webdriver

I want to add text into the edit box which is present in a PDF. This PDF is displayed within a browser when clicked on a Webbutton.

I'm trying to automate this step 3 & 4 in WebDriver using java.

Steps followed to get the PDF and submit:

1. Enter the required name and ID number.
2. Click on webButton OK.
3. Enter the Edit boxes present in the PDF.
4. Click on Submit button present on the PDF.
5. on click, The confirmation message is displayed on the UI.

Browser used: Firefox or IE.

I have automated steps 1,2 &5.

Any recommendations on how to automate step 3 & 4 are welcomed.

Comment: Are you trying to automate the process of filling in the PDF forms with data that you already have?

Comment: No. I'm trying to automate the PDF filling operation which a user perform and also these fields are present in the web browser.

Comment: The solution given is working? I also has form filling in pdf. I have few check boxes, drop downs, and input text boxes. If we have multiple input boxes, checkboxes.. how it will differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

The fields from your pdf form are not rendered from the browser but from a native embedded application or plugin, therefore they dont have html components and then you cannot access from selenium webdriver.

Comment: Whats the alternative?

Comment: there's not really good alternative, you would need a native test-automation solution to run your test and call this from selenium

Answer (score 0):

Hi TestGeeK if we talk about alternatives then you can do it like below

1. use Sikuli java api to insert some text in the pdf edit box
   http://www.sikuli.org/
2. you can use java robot class 
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

**UPDATE with sikuli**

1.First please download sikuli from here https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/1.1.0

2.now form download folder (SikuliX) take the jar inside your project

now the working code (working with google search on firefox)

```
public class WorkingWithSikuli {
    public static Screen m_screen = null;
    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // talking under consideration u have sikuli api 
        // in your library in eclipse project
        m_screen = new Screen();
        m_screen.wait((double) 3.0);
        // please understand that sikuli works on image recognization
        // hence when at the point u are entering value in the pdf input
        // make sure mouse is free nobody is using it
        // second pdf input should be visible not overlapped by any other thing

        // now working example
        // here i have taken google serach as an example 
        // in your case simply take a screen shot of the input box
        // and give its path in the below method

        typeString("C:\\Users\\rajnish\\Desktop\\gsearch.png","sikuli works great");
    }
    public static void typeString(String imgPath,String text){
        try{
            m_screen.click(imgPath);
            m_screen.type(text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not able to wait : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

here is the png that i used for google serach
**please pay attention here**

1.if u will not give the correct path of the png or

2.correct image i.e exactly same as the app has

3. please note sikuli clicks just in the center of the image (default) so take screenshot like below only so that its center is always inside the input box

sikuli will not work,so to avoid any further confusion please take complete snapshot of the input pdf box (you can take a look at my screen shot below for referel)
[image]
hope this helps you

Comment: if you are not sure how to work with the above options then please do comment i will try to post a working example

Comment: Thanks Raj. can you please share me the example, That would help me.

Comment: ok sure just give me some time also it will be helpful if you can name any sample web app as per your problem

Comment: Hope above example helps you in case of any query plz feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example. I can see this is a feature which can help to work on images and so ( Similar to UFT 12 object recognition feature), Because in a PDF, All the Images of an Edit box will always looks same than how would we differentiate every webedit present in a PDF?

Comment: yes this is how it works here in selenium  hope this helps you thanks

Comment: The possibility looks less has the objects will not be similar , But yes, this can be tried out to see if this suits.